# What Year did I Travel to Cape Verde

Tags: visas, payment-cards

I have travelled to Cape Verde over the past 6 years and cannot remember which year nor can I find any transactions relating on my back accounts.  Can any one tell me if there is some data base I can find out the year I travelled.

Comment: Have you checked your email for booking confirmations? Your photos you took there? A passport, a visa, flu shots, or something else you needed to get because you were travelling there? As far as I'm aware there is no such database.

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no database that records people's entries and exits to and from a country that is accessible to the public. I also doubt you could call the country's immigration and customs agency to request such information. The best you could do is to look for emails, photos, or any sort of documentation (perhaps a stamp or visa in your passport) that would contain such information such as a date.

Comment: This is not generally true though. For the US you can check your entries and departures for example

Comment: @Bernhard Where?

Comment: I recently checked it, some website considering I94 if I remember correctly